# Url Re-write for old urls is not working

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, web-config, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect my old urls to some new urls for some existing users.
Here is my source url:

[www.example.com/candidate/details/test-name/123](http://www.example.com/candidate/details/test-name/123)

To
http://www.example.com/jobs/details/test-name/123

I have tried writing the re-write url in web.config file as follows:

```
  <rule name="Old Url Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/candidate/details/.*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}/jobs/details/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

I am not very much aware of the url-rewrit functionality. I have followed some of available posts on SOF but could not able to interprete them properly. Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will work for you:

```
<rule name="Old Url Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^candidate/details/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/jobs/details/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Victor. Its been a long time when I posted this question. I found the solution at that time but missed to write the answer here on SOF.  I don't know if your answer solves the problem or not, but as I already had the answer, accepting your answer as correct. Anyway, thanks.